# Unity c# error quaternion is unrecognized in console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im getting an error saying "quaternion" is unrecognized

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;

    // Instantiate the Prefab somewhere between -10.0 and 10.0 on the x-z plane
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f), 0, Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f));
        Instantiate(prefab, position, quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The q in "Quaternion" needs to be uppercase for the error to clear.